# Drop duplicates but keep reference to dropped rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with many duplicate rows. The dataset has hundreds of rows and columns.

For each row there is an unique identifier. I want to create a dataframe with only unique rows. Then I want to create a mapping that maps the identifier in the unique-row dataframe, to the identifiers of the original dataframe.

For example

```
import pandas as pd

# Dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': [1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3],
                   'col_2': [2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 2],
                   'col_3': [3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 7]},
                  index=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'])

df
Out[11]: 
   col_1  col_2  col_3
A      1      2      3
B      2      4      2
C      2      4      2
D      1      2      3
E      2      4      2
F      3      2      7

# Unique row dataframe
df_unique = df.drop_duplicates()
df_unique()
Out[12]: 
   col_1  col_2  col_3
A      1      2      3
B      2      4      2
F      3      2      7

# Mapping from df_unique to df
# Creating this mapping is the problem
mapping = {'A': ('A', 'D'),
           'B': ('B', 'C', 'E'),
           'F': ('F')}
```

In this case rows 'A' and 'D' are equal, and 'A' maps to 'A' and 'D' before `drop_duplicates()`.

How to create `mapping`?

Here I used `drop_duplicates()` to create the unique-row dataframe. This is not a requirement. And the mapping does not have to be a dictionary if somebody has a better idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with `first` and `tuple` by all columns of DataFrame and then create dictionary of tuples:

```
mapping = (df.reset_index()
             .groupby(df.columns.tolist())['index']
             .agg(['first',tuple])
             .set_index('first')['tuple']
             .to_dict())
print (mapping)
{'A': ('A', 'D'), 'B': ('B', 'C', 'E'), 'F': ('F',)}
```